# How to select a records with timestamp ranges?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I mean that if I have table like this:

```
id | time        | name
1  | 1354382314  | test1
2  | 1374769114  | test2
3  | 1322759914  | test3
```

How to select a records, for example, that was created a week ago, month ago or year ago? Is it possible only with `mysql` functions or how can I do it in `php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's also possible with mysql functions

Like,

```
select * from table where time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
select * from table where time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
select * from table where time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since timestamp is a number that always grows, you can simply calculate the start and end stamp of your requested range, and use

```
WHERE `time` >= 'startstamp' AND `time` <= 'endstamp'
```

To get a stamp 1 week ago, you can use php functoon `strtotime("-1 week")`. Similar with month etc.

If you need current stamp for anything, use `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,time,name from your_table where (current_timestamp-time)>7*24*60*60;
```

7*24*60*60 stands for a week